# amazon-ecs-agent stops my application every 2~3 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

**Summary**

The ECS Agent, apparently, ignores my ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT configuration to 1h.

**Description**

I have a container that takes some time to complete his task, and because I'm on validation time, I've set the ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT variable to 1h, to avoid any influence of the agent on my applications. But every 2~3 minutes, the agent still stops my application.

On my point of view the Agent should wait the 1 hour configured before trying to stop my container, right?

That's the Agent log (Luigi and Model are my applications):

```
2018-04-09T11:44:06Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f]: sending task change event [arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE, PullStartedAt: 2018-04-09 11:44:04.75112162 +0000 UTC m=+628.146626082, PullStoppedAt: 2018-04-09 11:44:05.740402013 +0000 UTC m=+629.135906466, ExecutionStoppedAt: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC]
2018-04-09T11:44:06Z [INFO] TaskHandler: batching container event: arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f model -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE
2018-04-09T11:44:06Z [INFO] TaskHandler: Adding event: TaskChange: [arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE, PullStartedAt: 2018-04-09 11:44:04.75112162 +0000 UTC m=+628.146626082, PullStoppedAt: 2018-04-09 11:44:05.740402013 +0000 UTC m=+629.135906466, ExecutionStoppedAt: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC, arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f luigi -> RUNNING, Ports [{8082 8080 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE, arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f model -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE] sent: false
2018-04-09T11:44:06Z [INFO] TaskHandler: Sending task change: TaskChange: [arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE, PullStartedAt: 2018-04-09 11:44:04.75112162 +0000 UTC m=+628.146626082, PullStoppedAt: 2018-04-09 11:44:05.740402013 +0000 UTC m=+629.135906466, ExecutionStoppedAt: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC, arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f luigi -> RUNNING, Ports [{8082 8080 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE, arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f model -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE] sent: false
2018-04-09T11:44:06Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f]: sent task change event [arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE, PullStartedAt: 2018-04-09 11:44:04.75112162 +0000 UTC m=+628.146626082, PullStoppedAt: 2018-04-09 11:44:05.740402013 +0000 UTC m=+629.135906466, ExecutionStoppedAt: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC]
2018-04-09T11:44:06Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f]: redundant container state change. model to RUNNING, but already RUNNING
2018-04-09T11:44:14Z [INFO] Saving state! module="statemanager"
2018-04-09T11:46:42Z [INFO] Saving state! module="statemanager"
2018-04-09T11:46:42Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f]: Cgroup resource set up for task complete
2018-04-09T11:46:42Z [INFO] Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f]: stopping container [luigi]
2018-04-09T11:46:42Z [INFO] Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f]: stopping container [model]
2018-04-09T11:46:43Z [WARN] Error converting stats for container 823686bc5bcb5172a9f3d3fd6c0f4fd2a0fea924870f990f6a74475e6b840674: Invalid container statistics reported, no cpu core usage reported
2018-04-09T11:46:43Z [INFO] Task [arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:445147183740:task/22577c77-e2b5-4ca6-81bc-e9c214c1a23f]: recording execution stopped time. Essential container [luigi] stopped at: 2018-04-09 11:46:43.485611165 +0000 UTC m=+786.881116035
```

I've manually: changed the ecs.confg and restart the ECS Agent, to apply the new configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The aws-agent sends a SIGTERM to the container, the application must handle the SIGTERM to avoid the container shutdown. After sending the SIGTERM the aws-agent will wait for the time configured on ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT and than will send a SIGKILL to the container.

Example of SIGTERM handling:

```
#!/bin/bash

exit_script() {
    echo "SIGTERM captured..."
    echo "Cleanning..."
    trap - SIGINT SIGTERM # clear the trap
}
trap 'exit_script' SIGINT SIGTERM

while true
do
  echo "Waiting for the SIGTERM..."
  sleep 3
done
```

[Credits for the question to richardpen.](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1335)